# SVG's Not Showing - jsPlumb and html2canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, html2canvas, jsplumb

I'm using jsPlumb to show a diagram. Everything is working fine, the problem comes when I try to use html2canvas (1.0.0-rc.5), the SVG's won't show up in the image. This is the code I'm using:

Function that draws the connectors:

```
adjustLine (from, to) {
  jsplumb.jsPlumb.ready(function() {
    var instance = jsplumb.jsPlumb.getInstance();
    instance.importDefaults({
        Connector: ["Flowchart", {
            "stub": 25, 
            "cornerRadius": 5,
        }, {
          "cssClass": "my-connector"
        }],
        paintStyle: {
          strokeStyle: "#000000", 
          lineWidth: 2
        },
        Anchors: ["TopCenter", "BottomCenter"]
    });

    instance.connect({
        source: from,
        target: to,
        endpoint:"Blank"
    });
  });
}
```

Function that uses html2canvas:

```
generatePDF () {
  var myDiv = document.getElementById('content');

  var HTML_Width = myDiv.offsetWidth;
  var HTML_Height = myDiv.offsetHeight;

  html2canvas(myDiv, {useCORS: true, allowTaint : true}).then(function (canvas) {
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);

    var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [HTML_Width, HTML_Height]);
    pdf.internal.scaleFactor = 30;
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, HTML_Width, HTML_Height);

    pdf.save("my_file.pdf");
  });
}
```

Anyone know why this is happening? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution Brian?